# get analysis result with LLVM LegacyPassManager

Tags: c++, llvm, analysis

I'm currently writing a program that uses LLVM but is not a pass itself. For that, I want to utilize several analysis passes but not from a pass context.

As a concrete example I want to use the `RegionInfo` information that the `RegionInfoPass` can give me.

Now I have seen that LLVM has two PassManagers, a new one and an old one. If I get it right, the extraction of the `RegionInfo` -- given the new PassManager -- should be working with the following code (more less) ([source](https://medium.com/@mshockwave/writing-llvm-pass-in-2018-part-ii-640f680978ec)):

```cpp
void called_from_out_of_llvm(llvm::Function& f) {
  llvm::PassBuilder pb;
  llvm::FunctionAnalysisManager fam;
  pb.registerFunctionAnalyses(fam);

  llvm::RegionInfo& ri = fam.getResult<llvm::RegionInfoPass>(f);
}
```

However, this does not work since `RegionInfoPass` is an old pass so it has to be used with the old PassManager.

As far as I can see, the only way to retrieve analysis results with the old PassManager is to call `getAnalysis<Pass>` *within* another pass. Therefore I tried to create a wrapper pass and call it:

```cpp
#include <llvm/Analysis/RegionInfo.h>
#include <llvm/IR/LegacyPassManager.h>

#include <cassert>

template <typename P, typename Result>
class AnalysisResult;

/* This implements a dummy pass that retrieves the requested analysis and
 * "leaks" it to the AnalysisResult instances which creates the pass.
 */
template <typename P, typename Result>
struct Extractor : public llvm::FunctionPass {
    AnalysisResult<P, Result>& result;
    std::function<Result&(P*)> analysis_func;

    static char ID;

    Extractor(AnalysisResult<P, Result>& result, std::function<Result&(P*)> analysis_func) : llvm::FunctionPass(ID), result(result), analysis_func(analysis_func) {}

    virtual void getAnalysisUsage(llvm::AnalysisUsage& au) const override { au.addRequired<P>(); }

    bool runOnFunction(llvm::Function& func) override {
        P& p = getAnalysis<P>();
        Result& res = analysis_func(&p);
        result.result = &res;
        return false;
    }
};

template <typename P, typename Result>
char Extractor<P, Result>::ID = 0;

/* This constructs the legacy PassManager, add the dummy pass from above and runs it. */
template <typename P, typename Result>
struct AnalysisResult {
    llvm::legacy::FunctionPassManager fpm;
    std::function<Result&(P*)> analysis_func;

    Result* result = nullptr;

    AnalysisResult(llvm::Function& func, std::function<Result&(P*)> f) : fpm(func.getParent()), analysis_func(f) {
        fpm.add(new Extractor<P, Result>(*this, analysis_func));
        fpm.doInitialization();
        fpm.run(func);
    }

    ~AnalysisResult() { fpm.doFinalization(); }

    Result& get_result() {
        assert(result != nullptr);
        return *result;
    }
};

/* This is just a convenience function that tries to mimic the interface of the new PassManager */
template <typename P, typename Result>
AnalysisResult<P, Result> getLLVMAnalysis(llvm::Function& func, std::function<Result&(P*)> f) {
    // afaik this moves implicitly
    return AnalysisResult<P, Result>(func, f);
}


/* getRegionInfo is overloaded so provide this as wrapper to
 * make the function pointer cast to std::function possible
 */
RegionInfo& dummy_function(RegionInfoPass* rip) {
    return rip->getRegionInfo();
}

/* The actual program function that uses all of the above helper constructs. */
void called_from_out_of_llvm(llvm::Function& f) {
    llvm::PassRegistry& registry = *llvm::PassRegistry::getPassRegistry();
    initializeAnalysis(registry);

    AnalysisResult<RegionInfoPass, RegionInfo> ar = getLLVMAnalysis<RegionInfoPass, RegionInfo>(f, dummy_function);

    RegionInfo& ri = ar.get_result();
    ri.view(); // this segfaults
}
```

The problem with this code is that it segfaults when I want to use the analysis result. I'm not really sure why this happens, but it seems that the analysis result gets deleted directly in the `fpm.run()` function. However, replacing `fpm.run()` is not trivial (I thought of subclassing) because it is implemented with PImpl in an non public subclass.

Can you give me a hint if it is possible to run an analysis pass and use the result out of a pass context?